# How to pass parameters to Controller-Action using LinkButton Click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a list view for one of my controller's index action.
In that View's source, I have added the following code to the for loop present inside the source of View.

Thus i will get a link named "Select" against each of the entry present on this View. 
But I can't pass the parameters to my controller action using above code.

How can i do this - passing parameters to Controller-Action using action link Click?

Regards,
Kapil

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your case:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Select","ActionName","Home",new { iID1 = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["ID"].ToString()), iID2 = Convert.ToInt32(item.Id) },null)%>
```

null is the httml attribute you want to set for the link like
new {class="CSSClassforthelink"}